# How would one calculate maximum profit from jobs of different lengths while not crossing given time limit

Tags: multivariable-calculus, problem-solving, absolute-value

Given a list of jobs with length lets say varying from 5 to 200 minutes with different profit rates per job. How would one calculate maximum profit from the original set of jobs while the duration of the jobs combined equals to a given value (for example 500).

There can be many jobs of same length but different profit rates.

Comment: See "[knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)".  The decision version is NP-complete and the optimization version is equivalently hard.  There are polynomial time approximation algorithms.

Comment: Thank you @EricTowers ! This was the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\pi_i$ be the profit per minute for job $i$ and $T_i$ be the minutes spent on job $i$. There are $n$ jobs. If I understood your question correctly, your aim is to solve

$$\max _{T_i\in [5,200]}\pi_1T_1+...+\pi_nT_n\\
\text{s.t. } T_1+...T_n=500.$$

Assume without loss $\pi_1\geq \pi_2...\geq \pi_n.$ Then the optimal solution is to dedicate as many minutes to the highest profit-per-minute job as possible, then dedicate as many minutes to the next highest profit-per-minute job as possible, etc. until you exhaust your budget.

In your case, assuming $n\geq 3$, this means the optimal solution is $$T_1^*=200,T_2^*=200,T_3^*=100,T_k^*=0,k\geq 4.$$

Comment: This is the right answer only if you are allowed to do fractions of a job and what the OP calls "profit rate" is per minute and not per job (the question is unclear). Otherwise it's a knapsack problem as in @EricTowers comment.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks, that's correct. Not sure what OP meant, so I included my assumption of what was meant in my response.